# ReactJS: TypeError: this.ref.current.method is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need your help with to better understand the ref mechanism with ReactJS. I  made a custom component, and I'm trying to call a method of this component through a ref. However, I get this error that what I'm calling is not a function

I've got a "sayHi" method in my custom component "CountryInput" only displaying "hi" with the console.log

```
class CountryInput extends React.Component {
  sayHi(){
    console.log('hi');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <h1>hello</h1>
    );
  }
};
```

And this the component I used the ref in:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.countryRef = React.createRef();
  }

  save(){
    this.countryRef.current.sayHi();
  }

  render() {
    const {address, classes}= this.props;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <CountryInput ref={this.countryRef} />
          <Button className={classes.button} onClick={()=>this.save()}>
            Enregister
          </Button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

When I click on the button, I get this error:

> "TypeError: this.ref.current.sayHi is not a function"

I really don't understand why. Can you help me?

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code. In the message it says `this.ref` in your code `this.countryRef`. Did you already fix the code but are testing an old version?

Comment: I get no error : https://codesandbox.io/s/3qq3zwn9v6

Comment: chances are he's using old React that does not support `createRef()`, in 16 it works fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/m7v7nvrwly - needs 16.3+, though it should then whinge about `React.createRef()` not being a function...

Comment: Add a debugger/breakpoint in save() and inspect `countryRef.current` - i suspect this is not the code you are actually running and it is possible there may be a HOC that wraps the CountryInput

Comment: I've updated my project on CodeSandbox. Btw, please create a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem possibly comes from the version of React library which you're using.

The `React.createRef()` is available at [version 16.3.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1630-march-29-2018) (March 29,2018)

[image]

I've come to this answer because I've already tested your codes, everything works fine with React version 16.4.2

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/jvzxmo4xky (I've made an assumption about your Button component)

[image]

Comment: I'm using withStyles of MaterialUI to apply a style to my component, `class CountryInput extends React.Component {...}; export default withStyles(componentStyle)(CountryInput);` It seems it's to be the reason of the bug : https://codesandbox.io/s/l6mxmq6vz

Comment: Ok I solved my issue, when using withStyles of MaterialUI, I cannot use ref, I have to use innerRef ! Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: Thank you Thomas. This finding help me a lot. Can you make it as an answer, may be. Because this answer is not very helpful?

Comment: @ThomasDupré how did you solve the problem actually I have withStyles in child component not in parent

Comment: @Kramer, if you're exporting your child component with a withStyles wrapping, you need to use innerRef={this.myref} instead of ref={this.myref}